# Issue when using 1and1 SMTP mail Client with Identity

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-identity

I get the following error when I try to send an email through my Identity message service

> Error in processing. The server response was: Requested action aborted: local error in processing

my IIdentityMessageService is as follows;

```
public class DefaultEmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            //pull settings from web.config
            var client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk",
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword"),
                EnableSsl = true,
            };

            var @from = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmailAddress"], "GP Focus");
            var to = new MailAddress(message.Destination);

            var mail = new MailMessage(@from, to)
            {
                Subject = message.Subject,
                Body = message.Body,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
            };

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DebugEmail"].ToLower() == "true")
                mail.Bcc.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DebugContactEmailAddress"]);

            client.Send(mail);

            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas what this message means?

Answer (score 0):

**451 Requested action aborted: local error in processing**

The server is temporarily not unavailable. Please try again later at a later point in time.

**451 Reject due to policy violations**

The IP address of your e-mail server is currently blocked from delivering e-mails due to spam markers. Please remedy the cause of this issue and try again later at a later point in time.

source : http://postmaster.1and1.com/en/error-messages/

**Edit:**

If it keeps repeating, ask your SMTP provider to check the situation. (If you're sending a large bulk email with a free one that can be a common issue).